# SendInput while using a system command not working

Tags: c++, opencv, keyboard, mouseevent, sendinput

I'm making a program that detects a blue color, and according to its coordinates in the screen, the mouse will move / click.

The detection works fine, but when I add a virtual keyboard with the line "system("osk")", I have encountered a problem.

When the active window was the virtual keyboard, The program stopped working in the background. I mean that the program is running, but the mouse isn't moving or clicking. And when the active window is not the virtual keyboard, everything works fine.

Can you help me to know what's wrong in my code?

This is the code that moves the mouse:

```
void MouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    double fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1;
    double fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1;
    double fx = 2 * x*(65535.0f / (fScreenWidth - 200));
    double fy = 2 * y*(65535.0f / fScreenHeight);
    INPUT Input = { 0 };
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    Input.mi.dx = (LONG)fx;
    Input.mi.dy = (LONG)fy;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

And this is the main function where the command System("osk") is located:

```
int main()
{
VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;

system("osk"); // <-----------------------------------------
while (true)
{
    int xMouse = 0, yMouse = 0;
    float totalX = 0.0, totalY = 0.0;

    Mat frame, frame2;
    cap >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, frame2, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Mat hsvImg = frame2;

    inRange(hsvImg, Scalar(78, 241, 59), Scalar(255, 255, 255), hsvImg); // Blue


    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    erode(hsvImg, hsvImg, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(hsvImg, hsvImg, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    dilate(hsvImg, hsvImg, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));
    erode(hsvImg, hsvImg, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)));

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_8UC3);

    flip(drawing, drawing, 1);
    flip(frame, frame, 1);
    flip(hsvImg, hsvImg, 1);

    RNG rng(12345);
    findContours(hsvImg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    if (contours.size() > 0)
    {
        float sumX = 0.0, sumY = 0.0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
            {
                totalX += contours[i][j].x;
                sumX++;
                totalY += contours[i][j].y;
                sumY++;
            }
        }


        if (contours.size() == 2)
        {
            LeftClick();
            cout << contours.size() << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (contours.size() == 1)
        {
            xMouse = (int)(totalX / sumX);
            yMouse = (int)(totalY / sumY);
            MouseMove(xMouse, yMouse);
        }
        else{
            cout << "Too many Contours" << endl << endl;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
            drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point2f(xMouse, yMouse));
        }


    }

    imshow("Drawing", drawing);
    imshow("Original", frame);

    if (waitKey(30) == 'q') //Wait 30 milisec. If user pressed ‘q’ break the loop.
        break;
}
waitKey(0);
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this for those who have the same problem :)

We can instead of using the Virtual keyboard of Windows, install a VK from the internet and it will not be considered as a "System program" (if we say it like that). Then, we'll just need to open the new VK we installed with the code:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "VK.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Then the VK will open in the program and the problem is fixed ! :)